# AutoCompleteTextView list - Not displaying single word string first followed by two words string

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am new to Android application development and I am currently working on an existing Android application

I have an alphabetically sorted list of strings for the AutoCompleteTextView
and some of the strings have 2 words. when I start typing a letter then I would like to have the autocomplete list appeared such that it shows the strings sorted by the letter which i have typed

for example:
I have the list alphabetically sorted: free love, love, love letter, loveless

Now, if I type 'L' then first string shown in the autocomplete list is free love, the second string shown is Love but I would like to have Love as the first string because it start with 'L' . Thereafter it should show loveless, free love and love letter but it doesn't show in the order i have typed

Can you suggest on how to implement this in Android?

Comment: If you want the list to be alphabetically sorted do you check for 'L' in all letters?

Comment: I am retrieving the list alphabetically..Its an autocompleteview text box so when i start typing the letter its not sorting by the letters which i have typed

Comment: show me your code

Comment: this.searchBar.setThreshold(1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.suggestion_item, MyKeywordDictionary.getKeywords(this));   this.searchBar.setAdapter(adapter);
this.searchBar.setOnItemClickListener(this.suggestionhandler);
this.searchBar.setOnEditorActionListener(this.searchKeyListener);

Comment: Hi Kamal. Please refrain from signing your posts - we don't do that here. Your user card is considered to be sufficient to indicate authorship.